# react & Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, reactjs

I am from `Codeigniter` and just recently learned `Reactjs` and it was really amazing. I have not used js library or js framework before except `jquery`. I quite understand `reactjs` now and trying to grasp with `flux`. I am confused if `reactjs` is compatible with `Codeigniter` since `reactjs` also handles routing. If they are compatible, theres no problem, but if they aren't, please explain clearly and please give me pointers how to make MVC with `reactjs`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "since reactjs also handles routing" --- it does not care of routes, reactjs is just a rendering library.

Comment: What exactly you did not get?

Comment: Try what you need and post problem if occures. Check [here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) of how to ask.

Comment: @zerkms I need to understand clearly of how to make MVC with reactjs or do I really need to have it just the way it is.

Comment: @yul757 it's just a rendering library - you just render DOM with it. Your question is too vague: there are millions articles/tutorials on how to build reactjs-based apps

Comment: @zerkms i understand and I know how to do react. all I want to know is that is it advisable or fine if i use Reactjs and Codeigniter. Thats all.

Comment: @yul757 it does not matter - it just a client-side rendering library, it does not care what you use server side.

Comment: That makes a little bit clear @zerkms. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're talking about matching codeigniter routes with react-router routes.

well you'd have to set up a route in the format

`$routes[':any']= 'IndexController';`

i'll assume index controller renders a view which is the root of your react app. this way reactjs handles all the routing on the front end and all codeigniter does is point all routes to your app's root.